# I have two arrays and I'm trying to find the values that does matched and return. I've tried several approach

Tags: javascript

I'm using two sets of loops and I'm trying to find the values that are inside of a group and compare them to the array. I made a variable called boolean that's holding the boolean, but I'm stuck on getting the value that was not matched, how can I get the value that's not matched without creating an another loop?

```
function sayHello() {

  let array = ["go-fbce", "go-zio", "go-fihjw", "go-abcd"];
  const ids = [
    {
      "id": "z-333",
      "groups": [
        "go-zio",
        "go-fbce"

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "z-31993",
      "groups": [
        "go-zio",
        "go-abcd"
      ]
    }
  ]

  let group = new Set(array)
  let answer = []
     for(let j = 0 ; j < ids.length; j++){
      let value = ids[j];
       for(let k = 0; k < value["groups"].length; k++) {
         let instSg = value["groups"][k];
          let boolean = group.has(instSg)
          console.log(boolean);
         // }

       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Are you trying to put inside ```answer``` all the items from ```id/groups``` that are *not* present in ```array```? Please provide the expected output from the code above.

Comment: The expected I want is "go-fihjw" because that's the only value that's not in the groups array

Comment: Ok, so you would want the result to return the array: ["go-fihjw"]

Comment: Yes, but I'm stuck. I've tried different approach but no luck.

Comment: Please share sample of the data you're expecting

Comment: Are you looking to return the `ids` that match the groups in the array or you're looking to just return groups array

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve what you want with [Array.filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) method. Like this

```js
const match = ids.filter((id) => id.groups.includes(...array))

// match is an array of ids that match

const unmatch = ids.filter((id) => !id.groups.includes(...array))

// unmatch is an array of ids that do not match
```

Comment: `Array.includes` takes a maximum of 2 arguments and the second one is the index at which the search begins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that to get back the filtered result as an array.

```js
const allGroups = ids.reduce((accum, elem) => accum.concat(elem['groups']), []);
const uniqueGroups = new Set(allGroups);
const result = array.filter(elem => !uniqueGroups.has(elem));
console.log(result); // ["go-fihjw"]
```

Comment: I think you are in for a treat `allGroups = ids.flatMap(x => x.groups)`.